# When I submit a form it goes to unknown url

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Here is my View function:

```
def search(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        form = Search(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid():
            search_query=form.cleaned_data['query']
            #1
            pi=add.add(search_query)
            return HttpResponse('polls/search.html',{'pi': pi}, c) 
    else:
        return render_to_response('polls/search.html', c)
```

This is my url file:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^search/$', 'polls.views.search'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

And this is my template:

```
 <form action="/polls/search" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
  <p><label for="query_label">query:</label>
    <input type="text" name="query_txt" id="query_txt_id" /></p>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>

 {% if pi %}
    <ul>
    {% for p in pi %}
        <li>{{p}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No Results are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

When I hit the submit button it doesn't go to the same page. It always looks for another path like 'polls/search'. But, it is not mentioned anywhere in my url file.

can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

The form posts are made to url in `action` param. Since your action param is `/poll/search` it goes to that url.

Comment: Thanks. I want to go to the same page. But, when I put empty then it shows following error.

ValueError at /search/

The view polls.views.search didn't return an HttpResponse object.

Answer (score 0):

Because that's what you've specified as the form's `action` parameter. If you want it to go somewhere else, put a different value in there (or no value at all if you want it to go to the same page).

Comment: when I put empty then it shows
ValueError at /search/

The view polls.views.search didn't return an HttpResponse object.

Comment: Can you please tell me where is the problem or what can I do now? I want to go to the same page.

Comment: Why don't you follow the example in the docs? In your version, if the form is posted but is not valid, you will get that error. The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view) show exactly how to do it correctly.